# decoding a struct using Himotoki

Tags: json, swift3

I try to implement the decode function as proposed by the Himotoki library. My struct is the following :

```
struct NextItem {
    let question: String?
    let condition: [String : [String]]?
}
```

And I tried the following implementation of the decode function :

```
extension NextItem: Decodable {
    static func decode(_ e: Extractor) throws -> NextItem {

        return try NextItem(
            question:  e <|? "question",
            condition: e <|-|? "condition"
        )
    }
}
```

But I have the following error :"Generic parapet 'T' could not be inferred" for the "condition"
So the next question is how to implement the decode function for an array of strings

Comment: Nobody ? My problem is too hard to solve ?